# Querystring Issue on C# with special characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I came across a very weird issue where in my querystirng had "++" as part of the text. but when i assign the query stirng value to a string ++ will become two spaces. How do i get exactly what is being passed as querystring?

I observed that the querystirng collection had "++" but when I do Request.QueryString["search"].ToString() "++" gone, I checked in Immediate window.

I use C# 2.0

URL: /default.aspx?search=test++

```
string t = Request.QueryString["search"].ToString();
```

Comment: + is usually translated to a space in url encoding. That´s why they disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A plus sign in a query string translates to a space. If you want an actual plus sign rather than a space, use `%2B` instead.

```
/default.aspx?search=test%2B%2B
```

If you're doing this in code, then you should be using `UrlEncode` to encode this portion of the query string.

Comment: Thanks Adam... I had to do a regex replace on javascript for + with %2B, then call javascript escape(), and on C#, i had to replace %2b with + with regex and then do a Server.urlEncode()... all other characters are handled easily but not +

Answer (score 9):

You should use [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) and [UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx)

Those methods should be used any time you're inserting user inputted data into the query string.

Comment: And you can specify the encoding as well with those methods which can be useful :)

Comment: I was having an issue with my query string as well and specifically with the # symbol. Trying UrlEncode was actually not converting the # symbol to %23% although it is included in the specification as special characters! I finally had to perform an extra replace before i submitted the post. I hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

['+' is reserved in query strings](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt).

> Within a query component, the
>   characters ";", "/", "?", ":", "@", 
>   "&", "=", "+", ",", and "$" are
>   reserved.

Try using [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) to encode your query strings.

Comment: Will, thanks for the update, we can handle all other characters with JS escape() function but not +, i had to do regex replace.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there's a way to get the exact text passed into the query. The HTTP standards basically say that a `+` is equivalent to a space character, so if you want to preserve the `+` you should encode the query string, as Chuck said.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found was in this post [HERE](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/07928f74-b777-4418-8254-6bae2392142d/reading-special-characters-from-url-query-string?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious):

```
private string GetQueryStringValueFromRawUrl(string queryStringKey)
{
    var currentUri = new Uri(HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" +
                   HttpContext.Request.Url.Authority +
                   HttpContext.Request.RawUrl);
    var queryStringCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString((currentUri).Query);
    return queryStringCollection.Get(queryStringKey);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working on a ASP.Net 2.0 soluton, I had to do the following:

```
    private string GetParameterFromRawUrl(string parameter)
    {
        var rawUrl = Request.RawUrl;
        int indexOfParam = rawUrl.IndexOf(parameter);
        int indexOfNextParam = rawUrl.IndexOf('&', indexOfParam);
        string result;

        if (indexOfNextParam < 1)
        {
            result = rawUrl.Substring(indexOfParam);
        }
        else
        {
            result = rawUrl.Substring(indexOfParam, (indexOfNextParam-indexOfParam));
        }

        return result;
    }
```