# NET Core - FromQuery Datetimeoffset doesn't allow +/- sign

Tags: .net, .net-core, timezone-offset, system.text.json

We have a controller (.NET Core 3.1 Web API) which might accept a datetimeoffset:

```
public async Task<GetMessagesResponse> Get([FromQuery] DateTimeOffset? fromDateTimeUtc)
```

When adding the query parameter fromDateTimeUtc

```
...?fromDateTimeUtc=2020-05-11T10:00:00+0000
```

The response is:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-7b2339f4bfec9f419c728b49aed2b989-61a44f523e36fa4b-00",
    "errors": {
        "fromDateTimeUtc": [
            "The value '2020-05-11T10:00:00 0000' is not valid."
        ]
    }
}
```

While if I change the query parameter into:

```
...?fromDateTimeUtc=2020-05-11T10:00:00%2B0000
```

Then it works fine.
Is there a way to accept the +/- sign in the query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Querystring Issue on C# with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380388/querystring-issue-on-c-sharp-with-special-characters) `+` seems to be a reserved character

Comment: Partly. I expected (or hoped) that ASP.NET Core has a solution to implement a kind of encoding method in the JsonOptions to 'understand' the +/- sign from the request. We have solved this on our side by encoding the query "+" to %2B, but I expected that there is an nice solution in .NET Core.